# Problem related to Frobenius coin problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, divisors-multiples

Let's say that the linear form $ax+by$ represents $n$ if $ax+by=n$ for some positive integer $x$ and $y$.

Call a pair $(a,b)\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ with $\mathsf{gcd}(a,b)=1$ *good* if,
for any $r,s,u,v>1$ with each of $rs,uv,ru,sv,rv,su<(a-1)(b-1)$ (the Frobenius number of $(a,b)$), there is at most one set from among $\{rs,uv\}$, $\{ru,sv\}$ and $\{rv,su\}$ with both components representable by $ax+by$.

Do good pairs exist at all?

If they do, then is it true that for every sufficiently large integer $l$, there is a good pair $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in[l,2l]$?

---

A bad pair example:

$a=22,b=21,s = 16, t = 17,r = 19,u = 15$

$$10a+4b=rs$$
$$8a+7b=rt$$
$$9a+2b=su$$
$$3a+9b=tu$$

---

Related [Some divisibility constraints in Frobenius coin problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225047/chain-divisibility-constraints-in-frobenius-coin-problem)

Comment: A piece of advice. To receive proper attention and get answered, a problem *must* be presented in a comprehensible way. For your specific question, you can consider, for instance, defining the notion of a "good pair" $(a,b)$, presenting and explaining some examples of good and "bad" pairs, and only then asking whether there is a good pair in any interval $[n,2n]$.

Comment: @Seva Actually I thought about it, I am not sure $n_0$ has a good upper bound at all.

Comment: @Seva you think it is comprehensible now? I do not have an example for good pairs.

Comment: Well, I am afraid not quite: having spend some time, I am not sure I got right your definition of a good pair. The four conditions that you mention (if $av+bw=rt$ then $uw<0$ etc) all seem completely equivalent to me as you can switch $r$ with $s$, and $t$ with $u$; am I right? Also, do you have any examples of good pairs?

Comment: Doesn't the Frobenius problem itself immediately imply that the answer to your question is negative?  All numbers $n$ greater than $(a-1)(b-1)$ have a representation $n=av+bw$ with $v,w$ positive, so as soon as your $r,s,t,u$ are sufficiently large (or more simply as soon as their products are) you'll inevitably have a positive representation.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki $r,s,t,u$ can be such that each of $rs,tu,rt,su,ru,st<g(a,b)$ holds. But I feel pretty bad I did not explicitly state this. Clarified this. Ofcourse what I state will not hold if numbers exceed $g(a,b)$.

Comment: @Turbo You should really clarify the quantifiers in your original question, then - as it currently stands, the natural reading is 'if the condition on the left side of the implication arrow holds, then the condition on the right side holds' (this is what an implication usually means!) which is generally equivalent to saying 'for *ALL* values which satisfy the condition on the LHS,  the condition on the right holds'.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes, for all values for which lhs holds rhs should hold here

Comment: @Seva Simplified the writeup further.

Comment: It still seems to me that your condition can be stated in a simpler way: namely, whenever $r,s,u$ and $v$ are positive integers such that the products  $rs, uv, ru$, and $sv$ are all smaller than $g(a,b)$, they cannot be all represented by the form $ax+by$. (The condition with $rs,uv,rv$ and $su$ is identical to the one above and can be omitted.)  Is this correct? Also, since you do not have any examples of good pairs, it makes sense to ask whether they exist at all in the first place.

Comment: @seva it is slightly more technical. There are three pairs $(rs,tu)$, $(rt,su)$ and $(ru,st)$. If it represents one pair then it should avoid at least one member of other pairs. This is what I imply.

Comment: If both $rs$ and $tu$ are represented, then at least one of $rt,su,ru,st$ should be avoided? Or at least one of $rt,su$, and also at least one of $ru,st$? That is, you allow at most *one* pair or at most *two* pairs to be represented?

Comment: @Seva At most one pair should be represented

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question; hope it matches what you actually had in mind.

Comment: @Seva Just one thing (may be I missed before) I think 'some non-negative integer x and y' has to be 'some positive integers x and y'

Comment: @Seva Also to note http://mathoverflow.net/questions/225047/chain-divisibility-constraints-in-frobenius-coin-problem is stronger version

Answer (score 1):

I don't totally understand your definition of "good" so I don't really know exactly what makes your example bad. I filled some idle time trying to generalize your example of a bad pair. I realize (now) that that is not relevant to your actual question. But having found it anyway, here it is:

Your example of a bad pair $a=2\cdot 11,b=a+1=3\cdot 7$
suggests something like $a=n(4n+3),b=(n+1)(4n-1)$ The rest is nicely patterned as well with (possibly not on the first try) $u,s,t,r=u,u+1,u+2,u+2+n.$
A little fiddling gives

> > $$a=4n^2+3n,b=4n^2+3n-1,$$ $$s = 4n^2+n-2, t = 4n^2+n-1,r = 4n^2+2n-1,$$$$u = 4n^2+n-3=(n+1)(4n-3)$$

---

> > $$(2n^2+n)a+(2n^2-n-2)b=rs$$
> >     $$(2n^2)a+(2n^2-1)b=rt$$
> >     $$(3n+3)a+(4n^2-4n-6)b=su$$
> >     $$(n+1)a+(4n^2-2n-3)b=tu$$

--

Comment: Thank you for the time taken. The idea is simple. Lets say a linear form $ax+by$ represents $n$ if $ax+by=n$ for some $x,y\geq0$. Good pair $a,b$ essentially forms a linear form such that if $ax+by$ represents $rs$ and $tu$, it should not represent $rt,su$ and $ru,st$. That is all there is to it. I am looking for an infinite collection of good pair above a certain universal constant $n_0$.

Comment: In example above we have $a=22,b=21$ represent $rs=19\cdot16$ and $tu=17\cdot 15$ but also representing $rt$ and $su$ so $a,b$ is a bad pair.