# Some divisibility constraints in Frobenius coin problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, divisors-multiples

Let's say that the linear form $ax+by$ represents $n$ if $ax+by=n$ for some positive integer $x$ and $y$.

Call a pair $(a,b)\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ with $\mathsf{gcd}(a,b)=1$ *excellent* if linear form $ax+by$ has following property: For each composite $n<(a-1)(b-1)$ (the Frobenius number of $(a,b)$) represented by the linear form there is exactly one collection of divisors starting from some $t_j\geq t_1>a,b$ to $t_s\geq t_j$ at every $i\geq1$ those $t_{i}$ with $t_j|t_{i}$ in $a,b<t_1<\dots<t_s\leq n$ is represented by the linear form and no other divisors are represented.

Do excellent pairs exist at all?

If they do, then is it true that for every sufficiently large integer $l$, there is a excellent pair $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in[l,2l]$?

Note that every *excellent* pair is a *good* pair in [Problem related to Frobenius coin problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224953/problem-related-to-frobenius-coin-problem) and so *excellent* pair is a stronger condition.

Comment: Could you try to rephrase this a bit. I find it *quite* hard to parse with the nested conditionals.

Comment: @quid let me find the best way to put this

Comment: @quid there is only one if now

Comment: Is the following the same what you mean: "Call a pair $a,b\in\Bbb N$ with $\mathsf{gcd}(a,b)=1$ a reasonable coprime pair if linear form $ax+by$ has the following property:

For each composite $n< g(a,b)$ (the frobenius number) represented by the linear form there is exactly one maximal divisor $s|n$ with $s>a,b$ that is represented by the linear form and for this $s$ every $t|s$ with $t>a,b$ is also represented. 
"

Comment: I recommend retitling the question, perhaps "On positively representing divisibility chains with the integral form ax+by", as this seems what you are after.  Gerhard "Specific Titles Make Better Questions" Paseman, 2015.12.01

Comment: @quid I missed your comment and have now corrected to your language you have proposed

Comment: If I understand quid's reformulation, then $n \lt g(a,b)$ can never have three or more prime factors without being close to the larger of a and b, for then $s$ a maximal divisor of $n$ has at least two prime factors, and thus there are at least two maximal divisors of $s$.  But applying the condition to $s$, at most one of these $t$ dividing $s$ must be less than a or b if it is representable, otherwise it conflicts with the condition on n that all large t dividing s must be representable.  Gerhard "Clearly Confusion Is Present Here" Paseman, 2015.12.02

Comment: @GerhardPaseman clearer?

Comment: Is it clear to you? For example, can you see that for a good pair if t_j  is represented, then t_s cannot be ct_j for any composite number c which is not a prime power?  Do you see other concerns if t_s=ct_1 for such a c and representable t_1?  Gerhard "Six Is An Important Number" Paseman, 2015.12.02

Comment: @GerhardPaseman If $t_j$ with $a,b<t_j<g(a,b)$ is represented by $ax+by$ then $ax'+by'$ represents $t_{j+1}$ with $a,b<t_j<t_{j+1}<g(a,b)$ where $x'=x\frac{t_{j+1}}{t_j}$ and $y'=y\frac{t_{j+1}}{t_j}$

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I found the catch in my problem that made in unclear. your point was $2(a+b)\nmid3(a+b)$. This is not what I wanted. I want some $t_j$ which in this case $(a+b)$ divide everything above it.

Comment: OK.  If you find an excellent pair with both numbers above 13, be sure to post it here.  Gerhard "Is Ready To Move On" Paseman, 2015.12.02

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I dont have an example.. all I am saying is my problem had an error that misled you (now I fixed the error)

Comment: we dont have the contradiction you state any more since $z$ divides $2z$, $3z$, $6z$ etc where here $z=a+b$

Comment: So it's OK that 6(a+b) has two chains of divisors? Gerhard "Is No Longer Understanding This" Paseman, 2015.12.02

Comment: @GerhardPaseman yes.. i think your suggestion on chain made me think that way... that is not what I wanted.... my problem is as stated above (that is why I did not understand what you were stating) we can compromise as your chain is not same as my chain

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Your attempt below is invalid?

Comment: Since it is no longer clear to me what a chain is, I can't answer your question.  I can say for many pairs (a,b), there is an n less than g(a,b) such that n/2 and n/3 are both representable in your sense.  I thought that was helpful in a sufficient condition for excellent pairs.  Since the definition of excellent has changed, and since I don't understand the change, I can't tell about invalidity.  You should know what you want, and you should be able to tell me at why n/2 and n/3  being representable does not apply.  Gerhard "No Longer Understands Your Definition" Paseman, 2015.12.03

Comment: @GerhardPaseman take $40,31<  63<126<189<252<315$ Pick $t_j=63$. $63$ divides everything about it right?

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Shortened the definition to make it clearer (in above if $t_j=126$ only $126$ and $252$ are represented

Comment: I see two chains: 63,126,378 and 63,189,378.  Or even better, 126,378 and 189,378.  I still don't understand what you want.  In particular, what should "exactly one" apply to?  Gerhard "Really Time To Move On" Paseman, 2015.12.01

Comment: @GerhardPaseman your vision of chain is slightly different. If $63$ is represented every one of $63$, $126$, $189$, $252$, $315$, $378$ is represented (removed word chain to clear possible ambiguity) Likewise if $126$ is represented then $126$, $252$ and $378$ is represented (may be refer least value as possibly unique minimal divisor represented).

Comment: Fine, you have your collection.  Why can't I have my two collections 63,126 and 63,189?  Or if you want all representable divisors of n, have the collection of all representable divisors of n.  There is exactly one of those.  When $n$ has more than one maximal divisor and exactly one of those maximal divisors  is representable, then "exactly one" makes sense.  Your current definition does not, and at this point I no longer see how you can rescue it.  Gerhard "Perhaps Define Your Exclusions First" Paseman, 2015.12.03

Comment: @GerhardPaseman 'There is exactly one of those.' this is the ambiguity. Say you have divisiors $63<71<126<142<189<213<252<284<315<355$. There are many choices for minimal element. Once you fix that element you get an unique collection. This minimal element is ambiguous before the selection is made. Say you fix minimal element is $71$ then $71$, $142$, $213$, $284$, $355$ will be represented. If minimal element is $142$ then only $142$, $284$ will be represented. The point is $ax+by$ does not know which minimal element it will *touch* but once it touches one the collection becomes unambiguous.

Comment: No, you misunderstand.  Fix n.  Fix a and b. There is a set of all divisors of n.  Not more than one or less than one.  Exactly one set of divisors of n.  There is a subset D of divisors of n which are all those representable by ax+by in your sense.  Exactly one subset, no more, no less.  It is clear you want some subset of D, but it is unclear whether it is a proper subset, and it is no longer clear what "exactly one" applies to.  I have spent too much energy on this.  I stop now.  Gerhard "Someone Else Can Try This" Paseman, 2015.12.03

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Why should it be a proper subset? As far as we know, it has at least one element $n$ because apriori we assumed it represents $n$. All I am saying is there is only one unique minimal element in the divisibility condition. This is element $t_j$ which may very well equal to be $n$ in value

Comment: 15 edits by OP in 2 days.

Comment: In your definition Frobenius number is not $(a-1)(b-1)$ but $ab$: $6\ne 2x+3y$ with positive $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2):

As I read the question, you want find certain pairs $(a,b)$ to use the linear form $ax+by$ to represent positively only certain numbers, and only in a certain way.  In particular, for any $n$ with $a,b<n<g(a,b)=ab-a-b$, it is either not representable as $ax+by$ for integers $x$ and $y$ where both $x$ and $y$ is at least $1$, or $n$ is representable and at most one of its maximal divisors is also representable.

Well, you aren't going to find many such $a,b$.  Let's pick $s=a+b$.  Then $2s, 3s, 6s$ are also representable, so by your condition $6s \gt ab -a -b$, or $7(a+b)>ab$. So the smaller of $a$ and $b$ is less than $14$, and as $b$ gets large $a$ is bounded above by $7$. And we haven't explored what happens when you pick $\lceil  b/a \rceil a$.  I predict there will be only finitely many such pairs.

**Edit 2015.12.02**:  I don't see why there is so much difficulty.  I shall attempt a very clear explanation.

Suppose $7(a+b)\leq ab$.  Then $6(a+b) \leq ab -a -b$. Also $6(a+b), 3(a+b)$, and $2(a+b)$ are representable. Thus $(a,b)$ is not an excellent pair.  Thus a pair is excellent implies $7(a+b) \gt ab$, which gives a bound on the smaller of $a$ and $b$, namely if $a$ is smaller then $14 \gt 7(1 + a/b) \gt a$. When $a$ is fixed and not too small $7a/(a-7) \gt b$. The remaining excellent pairs must have the smaller number at most 7.  When the smaller number is 2 or 3, one can choose a larger coprime number to get an excellent pair.  This happens because the interval of representability is too small for the condition to fail.  I leave the cases 4 through 7 to the interested reader.  **End Edit 2015.12.02.**

Gerhard "Leaving The Rest To You" Paseman, 2015.12.01

Comment: Indeed, for $a\lt b$, what are your plans for $6b$?  Gerhard "Maybe This Is Even Simpler" Paseman, 2015.12.01

Comment: Indeed, choices are slim if you have $b \lt 2ka \lt 3ka \lt 6ka \lt ab -a-b$ for some positive integer $k$.  Gerhard "Finite Is Looking Really Good" Paseman, 2015.12.01.

Comment: Oops.  (2,2k+1) works, although somewhat trivially, as does (3,b) for somewhat similar reasons.  I think there is little hope for (6,b) though.  Gerhard "Done With This For Now" Paseman, 2015.12.01

Comment: I think there are sufficiently many in a partcular $[n,2n]$ if one exists in that particular $[n,2n]$

Comment: $b$ in $(3,b)$ is a number greater than and coprime to $3$, in which case one is looking at representability of numbers in $(b, 2b-3)$ which gives no numbers in that interval with proper divisors in that interval.  Looking at slightly larger intervals for larger values of $a$ starts to show the possibilities. So there are infinitely many pairs, but many of them aren't interesting from a divisibility lattice standpoint.  Gerhard "Been Staring At Lattices Lately" Paseman, 2015.12.01

Comment: And in case you missed it, $a \lt 7$.  So $n$ can't be  arbitrarily large.  Gerhard "I Mean The Second N" Paseman, 2015.12.01

Comment: ' I predict there will be only finitely many such pairs' is not a proof

Comment: Of course not.  It is a prediction that turned out to be wrong.  If my post and comments don't help you answer your question, I don't think I will be able to enlighten you.  Gerhard "Consider The Source Of Noncomprehension" Paseman, 2015.12.01

Comment: $a \lt 7$ unless $b=8$.  Gerhard  "And Similarly For Six, Five" Paseman, 2015.12.01

Comment: So are you saying $n<14$ is the highest $n$? Are you implying there is no such $n_0$?

Comment: You seem to be ignoring or not comprehending the point I make above.  So, let me ask you: Are 2b, 3b, and 6b representable?  If they are, for what values of a can you exclude them (otherwise I do not see a and b forming a reasonable pair)?  If 2b, 3b, and 6b aren't representable, why not?  Gerhard "You Are Meant To Think" Paseman, 2015.12.01

Comment: I do not understand ' Then $2s, 3s, 6s$ are also representable, so by your condition $7(a+b)>ab$'

Comment: You are giving in bits and pieces. It is hard to tell what state.

Comment: In your post you say you have finitely many possibilities only.. in comments you say infinite... which is correct?

Comment: The correct option is the one you have verified yourself.  I assert (2,2b+1) is a reasonable coprime pair.  Can you verify or refute that assertion? I say similar things about pairs (3,b) and (4,b).  Can you verify those?  Can you make headway on (5,b) and (6,b)?  Why should (15,b) never be a reasonable coprime pair?  Notice I have never proved that there are finitely many reasonable coprime pairs, only predicted that (and later retracted).  I have posted things to help you solve your problem, not solve it for you.  Gerhard "Believes In Individual Independent Verification" Paseman, 2015.12.01.

Comment: I think there are plenty of these pairs. I would not be surprised if for every $n>n_0$ and every $a\in[n,2n]$, there is a $b\in[n,2n]$ or alteast $\log n$ such pairs

Comment: I do not understand your insight on $(2,2b+1)$

Comment: How many integers are there between 2b+1 and 2*(2b+1)  - 2 - (2b+1)?  Does this help you determine if (2,2b+1) is a reasonable coprime pair?  Gerhard "Are You Analyzing At All?" Paseman, 2015.12.02

Comment: I think this comment thread has gone on long enough.